# Is there a name for something that was never told or implied by a novel, but that was decided to be canon by the author?

Tags: word-request

Sometimes, some authors decides to change his mind on something or decide to make something canon arbitrarily for no apparent reason, even if the thing the author claim to be now canon was never implied, foretold, suggested, etc. Is there a name for such a thing?

Comment: Is there any reason for you to think that this meaning has a particular single word definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the [Stack Exchange site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) for questions about works of science fiction and fantasy, the term used for this is "Word of God". From [a Meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9277/100430) there explaining what "Word of God" means:

> They're statements from the author of a work establishing some particular part of canon in their fictional universe. The statements are outside of the fiction in question, but they still count as canonical because the author said so.